# How to detect when ORA-00604 occurred?

Tags: oracle-10g, windows, hang

Today, between 3:00pm-3:30pm, my Oracle 10g database on Windows hanged twice. Error messages were related to ORA-00604. I'm pretty sure it was some query or queries that some user run as owner of some schema.

I'm checking listener.log, archived redo logs from that time (about 20 million records) and alert.instance-name.log on C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\admin\instance-name\bdump, but I don't find any anormal related to ORA-00604.

Would you suggest how or what else to search?

Comment: Look at the other errors that surround it. If nothing jumps out, contact Oracle support.

Comment: As @Mat said, `ORA-00604` usually has associated errors which should be under the `ORA-00604` report. Where did you see the `ORA-00604` error report?